# Understanding Dockerfile syntax?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am learning Docker and looking at this Dockerfile example for React application

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
COPY ./ ./
RUN npm i
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

To me it's saying

1. Grab image node:alpine from docker library
2. create WORKDIR called /app
3. copy the package.json file to the /app dir
4. copy the lock file also to /app dir
5. I don't understand what COPY ./ ./ is doing?
6. command npm install
7. then CMD npm run start

Am I interpreting this language correctly? Can anyone give me insight of what is actually going on?

Comment: You guessed it right. The line you dont understand means copy everything from context to /app. Oftentimes also done with `COPY . ./`.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Comment: This isn't a very good example to learn from - there's no point separately copying the package files if you don't install the dependencies until after you've also copied everything else. Also if that's a CRA app you shouldn't be using start, which is Webpack's dev server, as the production run command.

Comment: ^ whats a good example to follow for a react application?

Comment: It's not a CRA app exactly, but this shows a better pattern: https://github.com/textbook/react-ts-fe/blob/main/Dockerfile

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of `Dockerfile`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/)? Programming is about following specifications, not about guessing.

Answer (score 2):

Docker is an open-source containerization platform. Here we run our application in the container(which is managed by Docker Engine). Dockerfile contains all the commands. Also, you can say in Dockerfile that we write all the procedures to make a container runnable.

Coming back to your point...

Here `COPY ./ ./` meaning is, `COPY <source_path> <destination_path>` and `<source_path>` is the path in your **host machine** and `<destination_path>` is path in your **container machine**

I will try to simplify the other contents in your Dockerfile...

- `FROM node:alpine` 
  Pull image `node:alpine` from Docker Hub. Here `node` is the package name and `alpine` is the Linux distribution with very minimal and required packages.
- `WORKDIR /app`
  (Work Directory) In container you're setting up your `WORKDIR` as `/app` folder.
- `COPY package.json ./`
  `COPY` the `package.json`(host machine) file to `./`(current directory) in your container
- And other `COPY` will also work in the same way.
- `RUN npm i`
  `RUN` command `npm i` in container
- `CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]`
  `CMD` command will executed(`npm run start`) when Docker Container will start.

For more detail please see [Dockerfile Documentation.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#)